# SQL query that has a lookup field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Invoices that has 3 fields:

InvoiceProductCode
InvoiceQuantity
InvoicePrice

InvoiceProductCode can be blank, but if it's not blank, I would like it to be filled with a value from Products table.

- products table -
  ProductCode
  ProductName

Example 2 lines of data

```
InvoiceProductCode    InvoiceQuantity    InvoicePrice
3                     2                   5
                      1                   10  

SELECT InvoiceProductCode, InvoiceQuantity, InvoicePrice from Invoices 
INNER JOIN Products ON InvoiceProductCode = Products.ProductCode 
WHERE InvoiceNumber=3
```

I would like both rows to be returned even though 2nd row's InvoiceProductCode is empty (or zero), just that only the first row will have the ProductName; the 2nd row's ProductName will be empty. i would like to do this in SQL without using Lookup table.

So final result should look like 2 rows:

```
InvoiceProductCode ProductName   Invoice Quantity    Invoice Price
3                  Laptop               2                   5
0                                       1                   10
```

instead of just 1 row:

```
InvoiceProductCode ProductName   Invoice Quantity    Invoice Price
3                  Laptop               2                   5
```

how do I structure a query?  INNER JOIN on ProductCode will only give me 1 row - the one with the non-empty ProductCode, but the row without the ProductCode is left out.

Any advice?

thanks.

Comment: Look into:  LEFT JOIN - Returns all rows from first table, and only ones that exist in 2nd table.

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are using.  Also tag with the database.

Comment: @Brad could be my mistake... Left Join didn't work earlier for some reason. thanks!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I've just edited it. Mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `left join`:

```
select coalesce(p.ProductName, ipc.InvoiceProductCode), . . . 
from InvoiceProductCode ipc left join
     Products p
     on ipc.InvoiceProductCode = p.ProductCode
```